# First 2 elements of an array don't show in output after for loop

Tags: c

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>
    int main()
      {
        char cleartxt[256];
        printf("what do you want to cipher? (lower cases only)\n");
        fgets(cleartxt, sizeof(cleartxt), stdin);
        int len = strlen(cleartxt);

        unsigned short method;
        printf("do you want to use method 1 (Caesar's cipher) or method 2(scrambled alphabet)?\n");
        scanf ("%d",&method);

         if (method==1) {
         int key;
         printf("what's your key?\n");
         scanf("%d",&key);

          for (int i=0; i < (len - 1); i++) {
                 if (cleartxt[i]<=122) {
                    if (cleartxt[i]>=97)
                       cleartxt[i] = 97 + (((cleartxt[i]%97)+key)%26);
                       printf ("%c", cleartxt[i]);
                } else {
                       printf("%c",cleartxt[i]);
                      }
                 }
   } else printf("the number is invalid");
    return 0;
  }
```

I was testing the first part of this program to see if it worked so far, but in output the first 2 elements of the array are skipped.
If i remove the if to decide the method, the for loop works just fine and i can't understand why

Comment: one problem, you have the wrong format specifier for `scanf`. `%d` is for ints, so change `method` to `int method;` or use the `scanf` format specifier for `unsigned short` which is ..... ? Someone here will know.

Comment: @yano `%hu` will do...

Comment: ...which was a likely cause of the first 2 string elements being overwritten: 4 bytes written to where 2 are stored.

Comment: this solved my problem, thanks a lot!